# how to turn class based view variable to function based view?

Tags: python, django

In the classs based view I  can just go "paginate_by = 8" and in html I can do

```py
{% if page_obj.has_previous %}
     <a class="btn btn-outline-info mb-4" href="?page=1">First</a>
     <a class="btn btn-outline-info mb-4" href="?page={{ page_obj.previous_page_number }}">Previous</a>
{% endif %}
```

But for function based view, is there anything I  can do such as paginate_by such that I don't have to modify my html from what I have?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can implement the [*pagination* [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/pagination/) yourself, like:

```
from app.models import SomeModel
from django.core.paginator import Paginator
from django.http import Http404
from django.shortcuts import render

def some_view(request):
    paginate_by = 8
    qs = SomeModel.objects.all()
    page = request.GET.get('page') or 1
    try:
        page = int(page)
    except ValueError:
        raise Http404('Invalid page number')
    paginator = Paginator(qs, paginate_by)
    try:
        page = paginator.page(page)
    except InvalidPage as e:
        raise Http404('Invalid page number')
    return render(
        request,
        'some_template.html',
        {'page_obj': page, 'object_list': page.object_list}
    )
```

We here thus use a [**`Paginator`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/pagination/#django.core.paginator.Paginator) object to paginate the queryset.

This is more or less what a `MultipleObjectMixin` does to paginate the result. But the above actually already to some extent shows that for such views, you better *use* a class-based view, such that you can remove the boilerplate code.

Comment: not sure if you'll reach but do you have an experience with django-notification-hq? I read the documentation multiple time but still don't know why notification won't be read from unread........notification works but it stays unread even when it's already been read